# Python: deleting/removing class instances with none unique names

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, del

for a bit of context, I am looking to create a class called peasant for a game I am making in python. These will be the workers that will have many attributes. They will be created with a name and given an ID. Since the names have a chance to not be unique the ID will be called to delete the class. I think am going about instantiation wrong should ID be creating them with the unigue ID then giving them a name?

```
class Peasant:
    peasantCount = 0

    def __init__(self, name):
        ...
        Peasant.ID += 1
        self.ID = Peasant.ID
        Peasant.peasantCount += 1

    def died(self, Hp):
        if Hp <= 0:
        Peasant.peasantCount -=1
        del self
```

The  `def died` would be a method to kill my peasants if I can make it work, but the instance is not deleted when `instance.died(0)` is called.

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? Do they really *need* to be separate instances? What's the problem with `died`?

Comment: Also, what do these *peasants* actually do? It sounds to me more like you want some “peasant collection” that just counts how many peasants are there. And for that, you can just provide some `add` and `remove` methods.

Comment: So I just checked, and I don't think `__del__` stops working after a certain amount of instances, but given that the official documentation doesn't want you to use it, I wouldn't. (See the giant warning here: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__ )

Comment: the way you use it now, you are decrementing the peasant count twice. once you call `died` and when the instance in garbage collected (`__del__` is called). and both methods should have `self` and not `self.ID` as (first) argument.

Comment: I have revised the question with inputs from the previous comments. Hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: i still do not understand your question... and you need not worry about and id; they will get one automatically: try `p = Peasant(); print(id(p))`; each one will get a unique id.

Comment: and you need not worry too much about instances not being deleted when you think they should; the garbage collector will take  care of them at some point (it's just hard to predict when exactly) as soon as they are not referenced anymore: http://patshaughnessy.net/2013/10/24/visualizing-garbage-collection-in-ruby-and-python.

Comment: thanks for all the input I have made many changes to my code and learned much.